# Detecting touch events on bars in a BarChart

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using AcharEngine for displaying graph, my question is that can i detect touch events on particular bars of the graph ? Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you can.

Please take a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/XYChartBuilder.java) example, starting at line #170. The example shows you how to handle these events on the line charts, but it is the same for bars.

Comment: I had a good look at it but i cant figure out where.(line 125-159) its a listener set to button. Can u please explain a little if i am missing something ?

Comment: Sorry, I confused the lines. See lines #168 to #205.

Comment: Thanks @Dan for your valuable suggestion.